# How to ignore the lines starts with # using grep / awk

Tags: shell, shell-script, awk, grep

```
cat /etc/oratab
#test1:/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4:N
+ASM2:/grid/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4:N         # line added by Agent
test2:/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4:N          # line added by Agent
test3:/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4:N          # line added by Agent

oracle@node1 [/home/oracle]
cat /etc/oratab | grep -v "agent" | awk -F: '{print $2 }' | awk NF | uniq
```

awk NF is to omit blank lines in the output.

Only lines starts with # needs to be ignored. Expected output:

```
/grid/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4
/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4
```

Comment: Why is the `+ASM2` line expected not to be part of the output?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
awk -F: '/^[^#]/ { print $2 }' /etc/oratab | uniq
```

`/^[^#]/` matches every line the first character of which is not a `#`; `[^` means "none of the charaters before the next (or rather: closing) `]`.

As only the part between the first two colons is needed `-F:' makes`awk`split the line at colons, and`print $2` prints the second part.

Comment: this needs some explanation for it to make sense to visitors.

Answer (score 13):

Using grep: 
`grep -vE "^#"` or `grep -E "^[^#]"`

Answer (score 3):

The `next` awk statement will skip the current line, that is useful if you have to match multiple blocks in your script.

```
awk '
/^#/ {next}
/ pattern 1 / {    }
/ pattern 2 / {    } '  filename
```

Answer (score -2):

```
sed 's/#.*//'
```

This gets rid of comments, even if they don't start at the first column.

Comment: That doesn't skip the line though (and would even destroy/change non-comment lines that contain a `#`) but prints an empty line. `sed -n '/^ *[^#]/p' would do the job.